# .NET MVC Render Views with custom data annotations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

Playing around a little bit with a .NET MVC web application, and have questions about ViewModels and the data annotations.

Lets say I have a ViewModel:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [DisplayName("First Name")]
    public string FirstInfoName { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("First Information")]
    public string FirstInfo { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Second Name")]
    public string SecondInfoName { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Second Information")]
    public string SecondInfo { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Third Name")]
    public string ThirdInfoName { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Third Information")]
    public string ThirdInfo { get; set; }
}
```

When I want to create an Edit view my ViewModel I use:

```
@Html.EditorForModel()
```

This works great, MVC will render textboxes for me. But let's say that I want to render tabs in my view, So the properties of the ViewModel will be grouped depending on data annotations.
Example:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [Tab(1)]
    [DisplayName("First Name")]
    public string FirstInfoName { get; set; }

    [Tab(1)]
    [DisplayName("First Information")]
    public string FirstInfo { get; set; }

    [Tab(2)]
    [DisplayName("Second Name")]
    public string SecondInfoName { get; set; }

    [Tab(2)]
    [DisplayName("Second Information")]
    public string SecondInfo { get; set; }

    [Tab(3)]
    [DisplayName("Third Name")]
    public string ThirdInfoName { get; set; }

    [Tab(3)]
    [DisplayName("Third Information")]
    public string ThirdInfo { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to do something like this? Maybe using templates?

Answer (score 0):

While i'm not going to say you can't do this, it is certainly not going to be an easy solution.  The reason is attributes are evaluated on a per property basis.  Tabs are typically displayed withing a group, and there's not a good way to alter your html to include groups based on multiple attributes of the same type.

Comment: So I guess the solution is to create individual views for each edit page. What I wanted was to have one general edit view for all my edit pages.

Comment: Well, what you could do is group the properties in it's own type, then create an EditorTemplate for that type.